# Openshift Cronjob Not Running

Tags: openshift

I have tried to setup a simple cron job running on openshift but once I have pushed the file to openshift and then login and search for the file it does not seem to be there and there is not log output.

1. I created an application from: https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-go-cart
2. I then installed the cron 1.4 cartridge.
3. I created a file at .openshift/cron/minutely/awesome_job and set it as 755
4. I added the following contents:

`#! /bin/bash
date > $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/last_date_cron_ran`

1. I pushed to the server
2. Logged in via ssh and run `find /var/lib/openshift/53760892e0b8cdb5e9000b22 -name awesome_job` for which it finds nothing.

Any ideas which might help as I am at loss why is it not working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the execution bit is set on your cron file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not with cron but with the golang cartridge I was using which was removing the .openshift directory.

https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-go-cart/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

You should also put a file named "jobs.allow" under your .openshift/cron/minutely/. So your cron jobs will be executed.
For your ref: https://forums.openshift.com/daily-cron-jobs-not-getting-triggered-automatically

And the reason you can find your awesome_job vis ssh login is because it is under `/var/lib/openshift/53760892e0b8cdb5e9000b22/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift`, so the command `find` does not search any files under folders named with `.` prefixed.